# Remove invisible characters from a string

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio, unicode

I am using `mongoc` driver in C/C++ environment, and in order to convert a string from `json` to a `bson` document, I convert it first from `ISO-8859-1` to `UTF-8` using `iconv` since the mongo c driver has a problem with multibyte characers.

In some cases, my `json` files can contain **special invisible characters** (like for example a character that would be displayed as a space character in Notepad++, but I can see it in a `cygwin` console), which will cause problems during the parsing. Using `isprint` makes the program crash for these characters, so I am using `iswprint`.

I wanted to do something such as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    if (!iswprint(strx[i]))
        strx[i] = ' ';
} // strx is of type std::string
```

However, the value returned by iswprint is 256 for the invisible characters, while it is 0 for characters like ß

Comment: You convert from a single-byte to a multi-byte encoding because the driver has problems with multi-byte characters? Can you clarify? Do I understand correctly that your original input is encoded in ISO-8859-1? Can you give an example of a "special invisible character"? Note that `iswprint` depends on the current locale and is highly platform-specific. What OS are you running?

Comment: what type is your string? iswprint only works with `w_char` based strings

Comment: Are you programming in C or are you programming in C++? Please choose at most one of the two.

Comment: @nwellnhof It's those characters that won't be displayed for example in notepad++, but can be displayed in a cygwin console, also I am running on windows

Comment: @FUZxxl I am using both

Comment: @Hayt I am using a normal std::string, but isprint is crashing when I am using it

Comment: @Mansuro In a single file? What language is the snippet above written in? Please choose one of the two for your question as the answer might be different between C and C++.

Comment: @FUZxxl Yes in a single file, I am wrapping some C code in C++ so an answer in one of them would work for me

Comment: @Mansuro If you compile with a C++ compiler, you are programming in C++. If you compile with a C compiler, you program in C. “an answer for either of them would work for me”—that's not how this site works for reasons I'm tired discussing. Please choose a language (and only one) first and then you can get answers.

Comment: You should use a `wstring`.

Comment: @IvanRubinson Thanks it was so simple!